# Azure DevOps Pipeline: pipeline not triggered with skipped stages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline with multiple stages. The pipeline is triggered for the `master` branch, but also used in pull request validation checks. It contains a few optional steps that only run for pull requests.

```yaml
# build.yml
trigger:
- master

stages:
- stage: create_debug
  dependsOn: []
  condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
- stage: create_release
  dependsOn: []
```

Then there's another pipeline that is triggered by this pipeline and consumes artefacts from that build:

```yaml
# deploy.yml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build
      source: Build
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master
```

This worked until we added the conditions on the stages shown above. A successful build for `master` shows as this in the UI:

- pipeline build view: [image]
- pipeline build list: [image]
- for the commit: [image]

So plenty green checkmarks. I'd say the pipeline completed successfully. But this is not sufficient for the second pipeline to get triggered. I'm assuming the skipped stages are the problem. How can I get the second pipeline to be triggered in the presence of skipped stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deploy pipeline can be triggered as expected when the resource pipeline (build) is completed successfully, even if there are stages are displayed as **`Skipped`** in build.

[image]

For your case, you can try to check with the following things:

1. In the **`deploy.yml`**, use the full branch name to the branches filter on the pipeline resource trigger.

   [image]

   ```yaml
   # deploy.yml

   resources:
     pipelines:
       - pipeline: build
         source: Build
         branch: master
         trigger:
           branches:
             include:
               - refs/heads/master  # Use the full branch name.
   ```
2. Use the [**`if`** clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) with the condition to conditionally display and run the stages. For example.

   ```yaml
   # build.yml

   stages:
   - stage: A
     . . .

   - stage: B
     dependsOn: A
     . . .

   - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
     - stage: C
       dependsOn: B
       condition: succeededOrFailed()
       . . .

     - stage: D
       dependsOn: C
       condition: succeededOrFailed()
       . . .
   ```

   By this way, when '**`Build.Reason`**' is not '**`PullRequest`**':

   - Only stage **A** and **B** will run.
   - Stage **C** and **D** will not run. They also will not display on the UI.
   - If the build pipeline is completed successfully (stage **A** and **B** are succeeded), deploy pipeline will be triggered as expected.

   [image]

---

Comment: I've tried #1 which seems to have worked. Why would my pipeline suddenly need a different trigger? The pipeline is defined in the same project as the other pipeline. I've only added conditional stages to the triggering pipeline, why would that affect how the triggered pipeline needs to defines its branches?

Comment: @Bouke, This does not defining a different trigger, it's still the same trigger.
At most times, if you do not add the prefix on the branches filter in the pipeline definition, when the system evaluates and parses the pipeline definition, it generally will automatically add the prefix to the branch names.
However, sometimes after the pipeline definition was updated to a new revision, the system might not correctly add the prefix to the branch names when evaluating and parsing the new revision. At this time, you need to manually add the prefix on the branches filter in the pipeline definition.

Comment: Strange behaviour, sounds like a bug that should be fixed. -- I've now also incorporated #2 into my build as that seems clearer indeed. Thank you for your help.